# Proving convergence of $\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ using the Maclaurin-Cauchy integral test

Tags: integration, number-theory, convergence-divergence

As an exercise, I am trying to apply the Maclaurin-Cauchy integral test to prove convergence/divergence of some series. Currently I am trying to prove that:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}
$$

converges (this is a well-known fact since the sum equals $e$). However, I am having trouble with the integral:

$$
\int_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} dn.
$$

Since the factorial function is only defined for positive integers, I thought one could replace it by the Gamma function:

$$
\int_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)} dn.
$$

However, I am not sure how to evaluate this integral. Moreover, Wolfram Alpha gives the value:

$$
\int_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)} dx\approx2.26653450770\ldots,
$$

which is far from the value of $e\approx2.718\ldots$

How can I use the Maclaurin-Cauchy integral test to prove convergence of the above sum?

Comment: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ , not $n!$

Comment: @Peter Thanks! Edited

Comment: I don't see the problem to get a value "far from" $e$ for the integral. Who said that the sum $\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(i)$ and the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ are supposed to be the same ?

Comment: @Pickle: You say  $2.26653450770\ldots$ is far from $e$ (which may or may not be true, depending on what one considers as 'close'). This suggests to me that you think the integral should be closer to $e$ than it turns out to be. Note that the sum and the integral do not necessarily have to be equal!

Comment: @Zubzub I agree, but can we use this criterion here ?

Comment: @Peter The integral test tells us that if the improper integral is finite, then the series converges. So yeah sure, this means that $\sum_i 1/i!$ converges.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You are right, they need not be the same, I was just surprised by the value of the integral. In any case, my question was rather about *how* to evaluate the integral or simplify if to show that it is finite, which would prove that the sum converges.

Comment: This is definitely one of the more difficult ways to prove that that series converges.

Comment: @AntonioVargas But is it possible? Can you list alternative methods?

Comment: It's possible, but orders of magnitude more work than other methods. The [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) and the standard [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) using $n! > n(n-1)$ (then telescoping) are way more straightforward.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you, I will definitely check those out. However, if you can provide a method using the integral test that would be great (it is the objective of the exercise I set out for myself).

Comment: [Fransén–Robinson constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant)$$F=\int_0^\infty\frac1{\Gamma(x)}~{\rm d}x$$

Comment: @simplybeautiful Perfect thanks ! Please add this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show

$$\tag 1\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (x+1)} dx < \infty$$

in the following way: For $x\ge 0, $ define

$$g(x) = \int_1^2 t^xe^{-t}\, dt.$$

Then

$$g(x) > e^{-2}\int_1^2 t^x\, dt = e^{-2}\frac{2^{x+1}-1}{x+1} \implies \frac{1}{g(x)}< e^{2}\frac{x+1}{2^{x+1}-1}.$$

Since $\Gamma (x+1) > g(x),$ we have the reverse inequality for their reciprocals. Thus

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma (x+1)} dx < \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{g(x)} dx <\int_1^\infty e^{2}\frac{x+1}{2^{x+1}-1}\, dx < \infty,$$

and $(1)$ follows.

Now remember, in your Don Quixote quest to use Maclaurin-Cauchy, you need to show that $1/\Gamma (x)$ is eventually decreasing, i.e., $\Gamma (x)$ is eventually increasing. That's not completely obvious. Differentiating $\Gamma$ once through the integral sign leaves things uncertain. However differentiation twice gives

$$\Gamma''(x) = \int_0^\infty (\ln t)^2 t^{x-1} e^{-t}\, dt\, > 0\, \text { for } x>0.$$

This shows $\Gamma$ is strictly convex on $(0,\infty).$ Since $\Gamma(x) \to \infty$ at $0$ and $\infty,$ it has a unique minimum at some $x_0 \in (0,\infty).$ It follows that $\Gamma(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[x_0,\infty)$ as desired.

Comment: @Pickle You're quite welcome.